# how assembly programme compilation works

Tags: assembly, nasm, boot

does assembly start executing from top to bottom like other high level languages ?:

I mean this code should hang on the first line :

```
jmp $
times 510-($-$$) db 0
dw 0xaa55
```

but it's not cause it's treated as a boot sector (last tow lines have been executed),
how that works?

Comment: From wikipedia: _"the BIOS reads the first physical sector of the media into RAM at absolute address 0x7C00, checks the signature in the last two bytes of the loaded sector, and then, if the correct signature is found, transfers control to the first byte of the sector with a jump (JMP) instruction"_.

Comment: And that `jmp` in your code happens at runtime, not at assembly time.

Comment: Assembly does execute. Assembly code is assembled in to machine code and the machine code is executed by the processor.

Comment: Assembly code is assembled, not compiled.  There is no such thing as "assembly compilation."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> how assembly programme compilation works

Assembly programs are not “compiled”. You say *compilation* if you are translating from a *more* *abstract* programming language to a more concrete “programming” language.
For instance Java → Java Bytecode.

Assembly language → machine code is not considered “compilation”, because both “languages” have the same “power”, are both as capable in describing an algorithm as the other.

> does assembly start executing from top to bottom […]

When the CPU is powered up or reset, the instruction pointer is set to zero.
However, as [Michael has already pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70708379/how-assembly-programme-compilation-works#comment125000059_70708379), the BIOS takes care of several things before you can actually execute anything.

> […] like other high level languages ?

Assembly is not an HLL.
There are “high-level assemblers”, but these essentially have a more elaborate macro expansion system.

> I mean this code should hang on the first line :

At least do something like:

```
    cli       ; clear interrupt: disables all maskable interrupts
stop:
    hlt       ; halt execution
    jmp stop  ; in case of a non-maskable interrupt
```

A more sophisticated approach would use the ACPI, but that doesn’t fit into 3 LOC.

Comment: You don't really need `cli` before a `hlt` loop; that stops the user from rebooting via ctrl+alt+del which the BIOS's kbd interrupt handler will detect.  The usual reason for `cli` is *instead* of a `jmp`, on the assumption that there will be no NMIs.

Comment: @PeterCordes Thanks for the clarification. I’ve hardly ever used `hlt` for real.